# How can I forward all incoming traffic from the local network to a VPN tunnel?

Tags: networking, vpn, iptables, openvpn, routing

The router is forwarding all traffic from an IP range, that goes towards outside the local network, to this host (that is intended to be a VPN concentrator). Using tcpdump on the host verifies this.

The host has an OpenVPN VPN tunnel established, named `tun0`. We can access the Internet through it, so the default route is properly working.

Now, we've enabled both `net.ipv4.ip_forward` and `net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding` using `sysctl`, and added the corresponding `iptables` rules to allow traffic to be forwarded and NAT'd:

```
iptables -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
```

But traffic is still not being forwarded to `tun0` (as checked with `tcpdump`).

Any idea as to what could be going wrong, or what could we be missing?